# Need a dash with a certain thickness and length (and something above it)

Tags: punctuation, accents, superscripts

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{llncs}
\begin{document}
-\ \textemdash\ \textendash\ =\ $\equiv$
\newline
$\hat{-} \hat{\textemdash} \hat{\textendash} \hat{=} \hat{\equiv}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

And again, TeX is full of wonders for the uninitiated. The = and identical signs are perfect. The hatted - would be...if the hat weren't flying. And I don't even want to *know* why the hatted emdash rotates.

How would you do a hatted hyphen (in fact, a hatted minus) which matches the hatted = and identical sign in position and length/thickness of the line? (Dotted has the same effects, as it seems.)

Comment: latex does warn you about the emdash`LaTeX Warning: Command \textemdash invalid in math mode on input line 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-` is actually as tall as a `+` (which sometimes helps, but not here) you can hide the height with`\smash`

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{llncs}
\begin{document}

$\hat{+} \hat{-} \hat{\smash{-}} \hat{=} \hat{\equiv}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, smash! I knew the keyword, but not what it was good for. Smash is the way you deal with your TeX :-) (And BTW, regarding your comment, I never read any of the 100 TeX warnings, the point is I only use it rarely and treat it like a black box. In 99 of 100 cases it suffices, here not.)